# React + ApolloProvider + Typescript = "JSX element class does not support attributes" error

Tags: reactjs, typescript, graphql, jsx, apollo

Hej folks,
I'm relatively new to Typescript, I hope I'm not overlooking something obvious, here. :)

I'm trying to add Apollo to a Typescript project, to be able to consume data from a GraphQL API. [Here a link](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/recipes/static-typing.html#options) to the docs I'm trying to follow.

The issue I'm having is that as soon as I try to use ApolloProvider in my ReactDOM render method, Typescript complains (on the ApolloProvider line) about with the error below..

> TS2607:JSX element class does not support attributes because it does
>   not have a 'props' property

```
import { InMemoryCache } from 'apollo-cache-inmemory';
import { ApolloClient } from 'apollo-client';
import { HttpLink } from 'apollo-link-http';
import { ApolloProvider } from 'react-apollo';
import * as React from 'react';
import * as ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './components/08-pages/App';

const client = new ApolloClient({
    cache: new InMemoryCache(),
    link: new HttpLink(),
});

ReactDOM.render(
        <ApolloProvider client={client}>
            <App />
        </ApolloProvider>,
        document.getElementById('root'),
);
```

Any hint about how to address this issue? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

The way you're using `ApolloProvider` seems all good. This problem happens when TypeScript does the static type checking.

TypeScript was providing static type checking against an unknown type for props and state. In this case it's saying that we can't apply the attributes to the element because we did not provide a generic type P to define what props are allowed to be included.

Please check your `App`, make sure you define the type for the props or state if necessary. If only props type is needed, say `PropsType`, then your `App` definition should be

```
class App extends React.Component<PropsType, any> {
...
}
```

Comment: I tried to even use "any" as type for the props of App, as follows:
`export default class App extends React.Component<any, any> {`

That however did not help either.

I'm starting to think this is somehow related to the Typescript compiler used by the IDE: I'm working on PHPStorm. If I open the same project on Webstorm, or Visual Studio Code, the IDE does not complain about this line (or other small issues, which also seem non-issues).
I can see that Webstorm is able to load the TS compiler from node_modules (2.8.3), while PHPStorm can't, and uses the one bundled with the IDE (2.2.1)

Comment: ..and to add more on the subject: This TS warning does not prevent my application from compiling. That's why I believe it might just be the IDE firing a false warning.

Comment: For those who are still encountering this: Make sure you have `**/*.tsx` files in your includes list. I had only included `**/*.ts` which caused the above mentioned error (beside others).

Answer (score -1):

First try adding `()`, like

```
ReactDOM.render(
        (<ApolloProvider client={client}>
            <App />
        </ApolloProvider>),
        document.getElementById('root'),
);
```

if not work, replace it with the following:

```
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Then, in your `App` component's render method, wrap the content in `ApolloProvider` like

```
render(){
  <ApolloProvider client={client} >
     ...
  </ApolloProvider>
}
```

Comment: Hej Kevin,
Thanks for your suggestions. I tried both, but unfortunately the error persists. :)

Comment: Sorry that it does not help, I think it related to typscript static type checking, see my following answer, hopefully it will help you.